# Same size and width even if the content is higher card body

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

how can I fix these cards so that they are the same size and width?
Because if I add more text to a product on a card, the body goes lower, but the edges of the card remain the same.
I would like the body to be aligned regardless of content
It's possible?

```
<div class="card-body">
            <div class="product-name col-12 no-padding">
                <a
                    class="unset"
                    :title="product.name"
                    :href="`${baseUrl}/${product.slug}`">

                    <span class="fs16">{{ product.name.substring(0,20) }} <br> {{ product.name.substring(21,40) }} <br> {{ product.name.substring(41,60) }} <br> {{ product.name.substring(61,81) }} </span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="sticker new" v-if="product.new">
                {{ product.new }}
            </div>

            <div class="product-price fs16" v-html="product.priceHTML"></div>

            <div
                class="product-rating col-12 no-padding"
                v-if="product.totalReviews && product.totalReviews > 0">

                <star-ratings :ratings="product.avgRating"></star-ratings>
                <a class="fs14 align-top unset active-hover" :href="`${$root.baseUrl}/reviews/${product.slug}`">
                    {{ __('products.reviews-count', {'totalReviews': product.totalReviews}) }}
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product-rating col-12 no-padding" v-else>
                <span class="fs14" v-text="product.firstReviewText"></span>
            </div>

            <vnode-injector :nodes="getDynamicHTML(product.addToCartHtml)"></vnode-injector>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Feel free to give a more complete example (actually rendered html instead of a template, maybe.. with css provided).

Answer (score 0):

I am presenting a case with pure CSS + HTML. The idea is that you can see how to format the cards so that the bodies are the same size.

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <!-- Page Features -->
    <div class="row text-center">

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=1" >
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">card 1</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">+info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=2" >
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">card 1</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">+info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=3" >
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">card 1</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                    <p class="card-text">product1 </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">+info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>


</div>
```

[run @ codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/X8tYnkZJoL)

The key class is h-100 @ card tag.

Good luck!